# Complex aggregration view how to

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

Complex aggregration view how to

I have a table ( `Table A` ) with `[payment type]`,`[Agent],[Amount Credit]` and `[Amount Debit]`. Now I am looking for a particular view of this data .

I want for EACH agent a summary of his/her activity.

So Agent along the x axis with Payment type along the y axis with Totals of each Agent ther as well .

```
Transaction type      Agent 1   Agent 2 

Amount Credit                 

Cash                20   40
Credit Card         20   20 

Total               40   60

Amount Debit                

Cash                20   40
Credit Card         10   10 

Total               30   50
```

Tried everything and cant get this view yet .

Comment: You may want to post what you've already tried anyway.

Comment: If the number of agents will vary over time, there's no way to write this as a view. SQL is not a spreadsheet system. The number of columns (and their types and names) produced by a query is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result that you want by applying both the `UNPIVOT` and the `PIVOT` functions.  If you have a known number of `agent` values that you want to convert into columns, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select 
  case when TransactionType is null then 'Total' else [Credit/Debit] end [Credit/Debit],
  case when TransactionType is null then '' else TransactionType end TransactionType,
  Sum([Agent 1]) Agent1, 
  sum([Agent 2]) Agent2
from
(
  select  [Agent], 
    [Credit/Debit], 
    PaymentType as TransactionType, 
    value
  from TableA
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for [Credit/Debit] in ([AmountCredit], [AmountDebit])
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for agent in ([Agent 1], [Agent 2])
) piv
group by GROUPING SETS ([Credit/Debit], TransactionType), ([Credit/Debit]);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6db72/32).

If you have an unknown number of `agents` then you will need to use dynamic SQL but you cannot use dynamic SQL in a view, you will have to place the code in a stored procedure.  The dynamic SQL will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colSum AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Agent) 
                    from TableA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colSum = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', Sum(' + QUOTENAME(Agent)+') as ' +QUOTENAME(Agent)
                    from TableA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select 
                case when TransactionType is null then ''Total'' else [Credit/Debit] end [Credit/Debit],
                case when TransactionType is null then '''' else TransactionType end TransactionType,
                '+@colSum +'
              from
              (
                select  [Agent], 
                  [Credit/Debit], 
                  PaymentType as TransactionType, 
                  value
                from TableA
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for [Credit/Debit] in ([AmountCredit], [AmountDebit])
                ) unpiv
              ) src
              pivot
              (
                sum(value)
                for agent in ('+@cols+')
              ) piv
              group by GROUPING SETS ([Credit/Debit], TransactionType), ([Credit/Debit])'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6db72/36).  The result of the query will be:

```
| CREDIT/DEBIT | TRANSACTIONTYPE | AGENT 1 | AGENT 2 |
------------------------------------------------------
| AmountCredit |            Cash |      20 |      40 |
| AmountCredit |     Credit Card |      20 |      20 |
|        Total |                 |      40 |      60 |
|  AmountDebit |            Cash |      20 |      40 |
|  AmountDebit |     Credit Card |      10 |      10 |
|        Total |                 |      30 |      50 |
```

Comment: +1 that is an excellent answer - all things covered - almost tempted to delete my attempt!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to do something like [**PIVOT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
(
    [PayType] VARCHAR(100),
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    [Amt1] INT,
    [Amt2] INT
)

INSERT INTO #Table VALUES
('Cash','michaeljackson',1,9),
('Credit','michaeljackson',1,9),
('Cash','jq',10,20),
('Credit','jq',7,9),
('Cash','phil',1,2),
('Credit','phil',3,4),
('Cash','simplesimon',99,1),
('Credit','simplesimon',101,2);


SELECT *
FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT  PayType,
        Name,
        Amt1
    FROM    #Table
    ) AS sourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(Amt1) FOR Name IN ("michaeljackson","jq","phil", "simplesimon") 
    ) AS pivotTable;

SELECT *
FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT  PayType,
        Name,
        Amt2
    FROM    #Table
    ) AS sourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(Amt2) FOR Name IN ("michaeljackson","jq","phil", "simplesimon") 
    ) AS pivotTable;
```